# dotnet core api model binding not working [frombody]

Tags: asp.net, .net, api, .net-core, react-redux

I have created a simple .netcore 2.1 application using react-redux template where there is an API where I register the users. The controller is as follows.

```
[HttpPost("register")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Register(User user)
{
     await this._authService.Register(user);
     return Ok();
}
```

When I try to test this API using controller always user's attributes are returned as null. Following is the User model and postman request.

```
public class User : IEntitybase
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name {get; set;}
    [Required]
    public string Email {get; set;}
    [Required]
    public string Password {get; set;}

}
```

}

[image]

Since sending user as the post body was not working I tried sending user parameters as query parameters, which surprisingly worked even when I did not mention to get parameters from query parameters.

After this, I changed the API controller in using [FromBody] attribute which still makes user null when I send the attributes in the body.

What can be the issue here that it defaults to taking query parameters rather than taking from body?

Comment: Share your client side code for calling the API. Also, have you inspected the POST request using developer tools to check what is the content-type and also what json is posted to API?

Comment: there is an error in your postman request .. missing ":" for "name" and "password",
is that intentional for any reason ? And definitely use [FromBody] for the controller parameter.

Comment: what is the type of payload selected in postman?

Comment: Yes, invalid JSON request in the postman is the issue

Answer (score 1):

you are missing :

the current

```
{
    "Id" : "555",
    "Name"   "Some Name",
    "Email" : "EmailAddress@abc.com",
    "Password"  "Password"
}
```

what it should be

```
{
    "Id" : "555",
    "Name" : "Some Name",
    "Email" : "EmailAddress@abc.com",
    "Password" : "Password"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using some API client like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

Request should be GET
Request header should have Content-Type as "application/json", it can be something else but try this to start.
Set body as

```
{
    "Id": "123",
    "Name": "some name",
    "Email": "someaddress@server.com",
    "Password": "somepwd"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have not used [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "FooBar")], in model, then property name should match the POST data (case sensitive).

Hence in your scenario, in Postman,

1. Select POST Verb and put valid url
2. In Body select raw -> JSON (application/json)

[image]

3. Then add following JSON body -

```
{
    "Id" : "555",
    "Name" : "Some Name",
    "Email" : "EmailAddress@abc.com",
    "Password" : "Password"
}
```